# How do I retrieve a particular value when the table name, column are given in a SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @id int
execute getLastRaw 'subjectID','tblSubject', @id output
print @id

alter procedure getLastRaw @column char(20), @tbl Char(20),
@return int output
as
declare @dynSQL varchar(100)
select @dynSQL ='SELECT TOP 1 '+@return+'='+ @column + ' FROM ' + @tbl + ' ORDER BY ' + @column + ' DESC'
exec(@dynsQL)
```

I want to get the value which gets selected from the select statement. But it says:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getLastRaw, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT TOP 1 ' to data type int.
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Remember to read how this site works:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/27535

Comment: You need to read: http://www.sommarskog.se/index.html if you are going to continue to use dynamic SQL. When I see someone wanting to pass in table and column names, I know they are doing things that could cause trouble in their systems. Over generalization in databases is a bad thing. And this link might be helpful as well: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you concatenate @return SQL Server tries to convert the whole expression to int because of [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)
2. You can't assign @return outside or inside of the dynamic SQL because of scope: the stored proc and the dynamic SQL are different. Local variables are *local* to the scope only

You'll have to use a temp table: this is per connection and available for inner scopes (dynamic SQL)

```
...
declare @dynSQL varchar(100)

select @dynSQL ='SELECT TOP 1 '+ @column + ' FROM ' + @tbl + ' ORDER BY ' + @column + ' DESC'

CREATE TABLE #result (rtn int)

INSERT #result (rtn)
exec(@dynsQL)

SELECT @return = rtn FROM #result
GO
```

Although, it is just as easy and more correct to use a proper SELECT...

```
declare @id int
SELECT @id = subjectID FROM tblSubject ORDER BY subjectID DESC
print @id
```

Comment: wow...it worked...thanks man...yeah i got your point i just wanted to call that procedure in few other insert procedures but using the simple select one is much simple it seems....this site rox...i will be a regular user of this...i am doing my bachelors in Software Engineering and i feel like this is the best place to get and share things..thanks again for the quick reply...